# UDP Client Server File Transfer PDF

Tags: java, udp, client

I am doing a project on UDP client server file transfer in which a client successfully reads a file and transfers it to the server. But this works only as long as the file is a .txt
Any suggestions on how to make it work for .pdf files also. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: My guess is that you're using a `Reader` of some description, which is inappropriate for a binary file. But as you haven't shown us any code whatsoever (client or server) it's hard to say for sure. (UDP sounds like a bad fit for file transfer in general, mind you... why use that rather than TCP?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already implemented tcp and it works fine. I figured out that what I was converting the byte array to string and then writing to file and thus some error was occuring
 I fixed it by directly writing byte array to file rather than first converting it to string. Thanks for the help. :)